# Code keeps breaking no matter what I try

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, codeblocks, sift, feature-detection

Ive been trying to get my very simple code that I posted here: [SiftFeatureDetector .detect function broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162074/siftfeaturedetector-detect-function-broken) to work.

But it keeps breaking, it compiles fine but refuses to run.

I have OpenCV 2.4.2, Windows XP.

Here is what I have done:

I first tried it on Visual C++ 2010 with OpenCV 2.4.2, I have added all the libraries included in F:\opencv\build\include along with the non-free ones I have also linked the bin folder in linker: F:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib

But it continues to break at that same line. It is very frustrating as Aurelius mentioned my code worked on his machine.

I then took out my second laptop and installed codeblocks on it, I linked all the correct libraries and dll files but it gives a different error:

> the procedure entry point __gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll

Can anyone PLEASE help me fix this issue, its been 3 days now and i dont feel Im near a solution. Its so frustrating when my code is ok but the application refuses to work. Its obviously some wrong setting. Please help me fix this.

Thank you

I would like to mention that simple programs like displaying an image, itterating over pixels, changing color and detecting a color works fine, its this sift that is causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many similiar topics on stackoverflow like [libstdc++-6.dll not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404636/libstdc-6-dll-not-found)
Google: https://www.google.pl/search?q=libstdc%2B%2B-6+opencv&sugexp=chrome,mod=9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

To sum it up as it says about different problems.
First of all you are using downloaded builds. This builds can be done with different compilator version than yours and it's probably the issue.

Solution: **compile OpenCV on your computer, link those libs and use dlls then everything should work**